# How did the cat end up in the city?

Tags: stray

At the beginning of Stray, the cat is walking with his cat friends in nature presumably outside the city. How did the cat end up in the city at the beginning of the game if the city had been sealed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Nature or time made an opening.**

If you recall how the cat got into the city, you'll know that at least some pieces of surrounding infrastructure have degraded to the point a small cat (<10 lbs) is heavy enough to cause large metal pipes to fall. It stands to reason that, with this level of decay, the city isn't as air-tight as it was when it was first sealed.

Comment: Also note that it's a *long* way from the point where the cat first falls into the city to the place where you first encounter anyone or anything else -- and the intervening space contains a whole lot of blobby critters that are hostile to everything else that moves but hate the daylight so don't bother venturing outside.